# How to do a Dropdown Button with Mantine?

Tags: reactjs, mantine

What would be the best approach to render a Dropdown Button using Mantine components?

[image: Drop down Button]

I'm thinking of sticking 2 `Buttons` next to each other with the second one wrapped with a `Menu`, but not only it wouldn't look good with rounded corners, and I'm also not 100% sure how to align the menu with the full width of both buttons.

Plan B could be to hack a `Select` to look and act like a button but this also seems like it will have drawbacks.

Any other idea to achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen the component library for mantine, think the last button here look kind of similar
https://ui.mantine.dev/category/buttons

Comment: @Disco No I didn't and that's spot on. Thanks for that! If you want to make this an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the component library for mantine, think the last button here look kind of similar https://ui.mantine.dev/category/buttons